# Statues that move (and kill) only when not looking at them

Tags: story-identification, tv

I watched a movie or show (**NOT DOCTOR WHO**) on TV about statues that move (and kill) only when not looking at them. I'm 90% certain it was a Sci-Fi channel show (before the name change). I would have to say I first watched the movie over 10 years ago.

The statues were human sized, possibly angels, or gargoyles or something, I don't remember. They did not show them moving, but they did did show changed positions and poses (arms out, mouths open). Not bushes, and I don't think they were controlled but I don't know- I didn't see the end of the movie.

**I know there was a Dr. Who episode [“Blink”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(Doctor_Who)) featuring [similar beings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weeping_Angel), not asking about that.**

Comment: Not what you are looking for, but instantly made me think of [SCP-173](http://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/scp-173).

Comment: Do you remember anything else about the story of the movie, or particular visual images? Were the statues of humans or animals? Did they show the statues moving around when people weren't looking (if so were they costumes, puppets, cgi?) and if not, did they just change positions or did they actually look different (arms going from down to raised, faces changing expressions) when people looked away and looked back? Also, if it's possible they weren't statues but rather topiary bushes that had been trimmed to look like animals, then it'd be "The Shining" TV adaptation from 1997.

Comment: Also important, are the statues employed by someone? Do they have a (human) master that they obey?

Comment: What I can remember: The statues were human sized, possibly angels, or gargoyles or something, I don't remember. They did not show them moving, but they did did show changed positions and poses (arms out, mouths open). Not bushes, and I don't think they were controlled but I don't know- I didn't see the end of the movie.. It's one of those things that has kind of bugged me for a long time! The Dr. Who episode is similar, but the movie I'm thinking about featured just normal people trying to fight and survive.

Comment: The Doctor who episode that first introduced the Weeping angels "Blink" (Season 3 episode 10) was focused around normal people.  There were Human-sized angel statues that would only move when not looked at.  One of the characters owned a video rental shop, and there was a bit about exploring an abandoned house.

Comment: Was there definitely more than one statue/monster?

Comment: My suggestion would be to (re-)watch "Blink", and then let us know whether you really were remembering something else. Because *everything* in your description practically screams "weeping angels".

Comment: Not to mention that Blink isn't the only Doctor Who episode that featured the Weeping Angels...

Comment: I just re-watched that episode. The monsters are similar, but in the movie I'm trying to find out, they were actually killing people, not just sending them back in time.

Comment: @SalemLowe they kill more in some of the later episodes. Personally I think you're talking about the two part episode Time of Angels/Flesh and Stone (reasons given in my answer). Any information about the plot/characters would help narrow it down!

Comment: I think I've seen an episode of Tales From The Crypt years ago that was something like you describe...

Comment: @SalemLowe: I distinctly remember there is an episode where the doctor says that the angels "snaps you neck" and kills you, not sending you back in time. But I do not remember which episode that is. I think the episode is with Amy.

Comment: @K-H-W heh, it made me think of the ghosts in (any) Nintendo Mario..

Answer (score 2):

Your question reminded me an episode of 'Tales from the Dark Side' entitled "[Mary, Mary](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0716959/?ref_=ttep_ep2)".

The episode features department store mannequins which move around when not watching them. A woman slowly, leg by leg, arm by arm becomes one of them.

[image]

You can watch it online [here](https://myspace.com/luckmurda/video/tales-from-the-darkside-402-mary-mary.mpg/43760624)

Answer (score 2):

This program sounds a lot like an episode of Kolchak: The Night Stalker (1975).

The Trevi Collection (ep. 14):  Kolchak finds an evil witch in the high fashion industry, who is maiming and killing her competitors.  A group of bewitched mannequins is doing the actual killing.  This episode can be found on youtube: